# Naming conventions, array the objects in typescripts?

Tags: oop, typescript

im confused how defined correctly a structure into typescript, for array the objects, for example:

I have a class **Serie** implements **SeriesInterface (Series)**

```
export class Serie implements DeserializeInterface<SeriesInterface> {
    serie: SeriesInterface[] = [];
    serie_id: number;
    serie_url: string;
    public addSerie(r) { // this method is for my JSON
        const serie = new Serie().deserialize(r);
        this.serie.push(serie);
        console.log(this.series);
    }
}
```

For the console, it looks like this:

```
(2) [Serie, Serie]
```

But what I would really like to appear is the following relationship:

```
Series [serie, serie]
```

I definitely have a series of class, and its plural is series, I can not find the correct way to implement

and looks if can see series[serie, serie] and this is a JSON

```
[
{
serie_id: 1,
serie_name: "Serie 1",
serie_url: "http://www.serie1.com"

},
{
serie_id: 2,
serie_name: "Serie 2",
serie_url: "http://serie2.com"
}
]
```

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Automatically change singular to plural???

Comment: @unional change this > (2) [Serie, Serie] to Series [serie, serie]

Comment: That's what `console.log()` does. Have nothing to do with TS and not possible to change (unless you override its mechanism).